# How do you run a command prior to including a component Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to create a subdirectory in my project (let's call it `$PROJECT/child`) that needs to pull in a Makefile (let's call it `../Makefile.inc`) from its parent, `$PROJECT/Makefile.inc`. Later I want to copy `$PROJECT/child` somewhere else so it can run independently of `$PROJECT`.

There is a common Makefile that needs to be included in both projects and shipped when the subdirectory is copied, and I want it to be included in both cases. So I thought I would link it in during the `child` build, if it isn't found. (I don't want to just include `../Makefile.inc`, because this will disappear when I copy the project, and I don't want the calling build system to be responsible for putting the `Makefile.inc` in place.)

With those constraints, here's a horrible hack that I've come up with to do this, within `$PROJECT/child/Makefile`:

```
HACK = $(shell test -f Makefile.inc || ln -f  ../Makefile.inc .)
include $(HACK)Makefile.inc
```

Notice the extra special duct tape on that second command. I have to actually include `$(HACK)` even though it's going to end up empty, so that the `$(shell ...)` will be evaluated. ;-)

Is there a cleaner way to make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a rule to build `Makefile.inc`. (`make` will complain that `Makefile.inc` doesn't exist when it parses the `include` line, but it will go on parsing the main makefile, apply any rule to build included files, and [go back and re-parse the main makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles) with the included files.)

```
include Makefile.inc
Makefile.inc:
        ln ../Makefile.inc $@
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks. I added a comment to make it clear to the casual observer what was happening.